# Why isn't my verified domain showing in the "add a new custom domain" page of the Google App Engine console?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm sharing this information with a self-answered question to prevent other people wasting as much time as I did with this issue.

The procedure for linking a custom domain to a Google App Engine site seems pretty straightforward but there is an important detail missing from both the documentation and the user interface.

Here's what I did, and why it didn't work:

1. Go to the Settings / Custom Domains page in Google App Engine
2. Click the "add a custom domain" button
3. Select "verify a new domain" and enter the naked domain name. This takes you to the Webmaster Central interface for verifying a domain.
4. There is a drop-down box saying "select your domain registrar or provider", with only a very limited selection of providers.

This is where I went wrong. Because my domain registrar doesn't appear in the list, and I failed to see the "other" option at the bottom of the list, and there are no other proof-of-ownership options available, I clicked the "not now" button. This takes you to a screen listing your already verified "properties", and a button labelled "add a property". I clicked the "add a property" button and entered the domain name. That took me to a screen saying the recommended method of proving ownership is to upload an HTML file. I thought that seems much more sensible that selecting my domain registrar from a list, so I went ahead and did that. After that process is complete I now see the domain listed as a verified property in the list, e.g. "http://example.com". When I then go back to the GAE custom domains screen, it is meant to allow me to select that verified domain, but it doesn't appear. I contacted google support and after several days sending many emails containing screenshots of every step and answering all of their questions multiple times they were unable to resolve or explain the issue. I eventually figured out the problem myself.

What Google fails to mention in its domain verification interface and its documentation is that verifying a domain is not the same as verifying a URL. Uploading an HTML file only verifies the URL (e.g. http://example.com/), but GAE needs the domain to be verified (e.g. example.com). When you click the "add a property" button the interface only allows you to verify the URL even if you type in the domain. The only way to verify the domain is by adding a DNS TXT entry, which you can only do by selecting the "other" domain registrar from the bottom of the list when GAE fist takes you to Webmaster Central.

So the correct procedure, continued from above, is:

5. Scroll down to the bottom of the domain registrar list and select "other"
6. Follow the instructions to add the specified TXT record to the DNS configuration of your domain, and click the Verify button.

When complete, the domain will appear as a verified "property" in the list as the pure domain name, not a URL. Now it should appear in the list of domains you can link to the GAE project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the domain is verified using the DNS TXT record method, not uploading an HTML file, as the latter does not verify full ownership of the domain as required by Google App Engine.